# Conversion from quarters into pennies

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck on making a modulist on JS for the conversion from quarters into pennies, here is what I got so far. What am I missing?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Bicycle</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Program: Problem 5
//Purpose: calculate the number of quarters a person will get in return when they enter the number of pennies they have
//Author: Zach
//Date last modified: 2/9/12
var entrmoney = ""
var totnum = "The total number of quarters needed is "
var totcents = "left over"
entrmoney = prompt("How much money do you want to turn into Quarters,enter in pennies?")

document.write(totnum + + totcents)

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem, what doesn't work?

Comment: I don't see any calculation going on?

Comment: I'm unsure of the calculation it requires.

Comment: You are missing your calculation =). `var numQuarters = +entrmoney / 25;` Then you need to round down to the nearest quarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to do some calculation on the entered pennies.

JSFiddle seems to be down so I haven't tried the code, but something like this should calculate the number of quarters and the remaining pennies:

```
var entrmoney = parseInt(prompt("How much money do you want to turn into Quarters,enter in pennies?"), 10);
var totnum = "The total number of quarters needed is "
var totcents = "left over"
var quarters = Math.floor(entrmoney / 25);
var pennies = entrmoney % 25; 

document.write(totnum + quarters + totcents + pennies)
```

Comment: How would I go about it saying the left over? Say you convert 28 pennies, how would I make it say, "The total number of quarters needed is, and ___ left over"?

Comment: It's in the solution by the looks of it. The modulus operator handles it.

Comment: Not seeming to give me an output with "The total number of quarters needed is  and left over is"

Comment: Ah, I caught it; Christofer misspelled `quarters`. I fixed it, it should work now.

Comment: @user1199777 You're the one who marks solutions, not me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your forgetting the conversion try

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Bicycle</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Program: Problem 5
//Purpose: calculate the number of quarters a person will get in return when they enter the number of pennies they have
//Author: Zach Salih
//Date last modified: 2/9/12
var entrmoney = "";
var totnum = "The total number of quarters needed is ";
var totcents = "left over";
entrmoney = prompt("How much money do you want to turn into Quarters,enter in pennies?");
entrmoney = entrmoney/25;
document.write(totnum + entremoney + totcents);

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not getting an output from it. :S

Comment: Also, what if a user enters 28 cents or something? Should there be a remainder?

Comment: Yes, it would say the cents left over.

Comment: How would I go about adding that?

Comment: Use the code Christofer Eliasson posted